# Союз "и" и вводное слово "значит"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, вводные-слова, однородные-члены

> Ты можешь быть уголовником, убийцей, насильником, наркоторговцем, растлителем малолетних, можешь воровать по мелочи или по-крупному ― в этом случае для государства, для системы, для режима ты не представляешь угрозы, **и значит**, можешь рассчитывать на снисхождение. [Андрей Андреев. Будущее принадлежит нам! (2003) // «Завтра», 2003.08.22]

Почему обособляется союз "и" вместе с вводным словом "значит"? Союз вроде как относится к структуре предложения, а именно соединяет однородные сказуемые *не представляешь* и *можешь рассчитывать*. Неужели автор самовольно "спаял" союз и вводное слово в неразложимое вводное сочетание? Можно ли так делать?

*А теперь в комментариях напишите тему, которая волнует вас больше всего, — **и возможно**, на эту тему вы тоже увидите пост в моём блоге.* (По идее перед "возможно" нужна запятая.)

И последний вопрос от меня как начинающего в изучении русского языка на профессиональной основе: можно ли ориентироваться на Нацкорпус в плане грамматики? Бывают ли там грамматические ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написала так:

1) ...для режима ты не представляешь угрозы **и, значит,** можешь рассчитывать на снисхождение.  Союз И соединяет однородные члены.

2) А теперь в комментариях укажите тему, которая волнует вас больше всего,  **и, возможно,** в моем блоге вы найдете (уже есть) интересующий вас материал. Союз И в сложносочиненном предложении.

В обоих случаях вводное слово обособляется, а чтобы избежать скопления знаков препинания,  желательно редактировать предложение.  Кстати, второе высказывание явно требует стилистической правки (повторы, лишние слова).

А теперь о слове ***значит***

Если вы планируете серьезно изучать русский язык, то начать это можно **с написания диссертации на тему вводного слова "значит"** (ну не для публики, а лично для себя, для развития лингвистического мышления).

Наберите *значит* в поисковике нашего сайта, и он предложит вам 50 страниц на эту тему. Очень полезный практический материал, но его изучение требует системного подхода, иначе там можно просто  "утонуть" и перестать понимать даже то, что было ясно до этого.

**Что тут можно посоветовать?** У нас есть два раздела науки, **грамматика и пунктуация,** которые иногда плохо понимают друг друга. К примеру, предложение бессоюзное, а  слово "значит"  нам предлагают считать союзом. Нелогично!

Вот интересная ссылка на тему "нововведение или новоразведение"  http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=3245  Обратим внимание на то, что в новых правилах "значит" в БСП является **союзом (!)** и не обособляется, в то время как Розенталь называет его словом и обособляет.

А в новых правилах и вообще-то нет БСП и СПП, есть "обобщенное" сложное предложение. Очень удобно, ничего лишнего! И  примерно ясно, какая нас ждет перспектива.

Поэтому (**по Розенталю**) анализ начинайте с грамматики, то есть с определения вида синтаксической структуры (однородные члены, БСП, СПП, ССП), а уже потом определяйте функцию слов "значит, а значит".

**А по новым правилам?** В этом случае используйте "значит" в середине предложения и где-нибудь подальше от союзов. Тогда это уж точно будет обособленное вводное слово.

Comment: Нельзя объявить слово *значит* только союзом. Пример:   Вот, значит, по ком моя Маруся все глаза выплакала! [Александр Дорофеев. Эле-Фантик // «Мурзилка», 2003]

Comment: А кто его объявляет только союзом? В середине предложения это вводное слово. А вообще у него много функций: сказуемое, связка, в составе подчинительного союза в СПП, структурный элемент в БСП.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ссылку!

Comment: "В составе подчинительного союза в СПП" — вы имеете в виду союз "если..., значит..."? Кстати после "значит" в этом составном союзе по новым правилам тоже запятая не ставится, так?

Comment: Не думаю. У Розенталя такой пример разбирается, там запятая ставится: п 9. (12) Прозвенел звонок, значит, урок кончился;http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122  Грамота.ру (запятая ставится): http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?id=58_220&layout=item. В справочнике  по пунктуации 2012 года тоже ставится. А в ПАС этот пример, кажется, не разбирается.

Answer (score 1):

Да не самоволкой автор спаял. Это единый союз. Хотя и очень похожий на вводное.

**ЗНАЧИТ, *союз*.** Таким образом, следовательно. *Тучи собираются, з. будет дождь. Ты сердишься, з. ты не прав.* **<А значит; и значит, *союз***. И поэтому, стало быть, следовательно. *Проезжаю родные места, и з. увижу своих племянников.*

**ЗНАЧИТ, *вводн. сл.*** *Разг*. Следовательно, стало быть. *От воды идёт пар, з., вода теплее воздуха. Вещи собраны, з., уезжаете?*

**[источник](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82&all=x)**

---

> А теперь в комментариях напишите тему, которая волнует вас больше
>   всего, — и возможно, на эту тему вы тоже увидите пост в моём блоге.

Ну куда лепить столько знаков?! Есть же ещё в языке и эстетические критерии.

С одной стороны...

> *Феде нужен капитал, старуха, чтобы содержать гения кота и, возможно, жену Аню, которой я сейчас сделаю предложение.* Э. Радзинский, Старая
>   актриса на роль жены Достоевского.

...а с другой стороны, при переломе конструкции, когда предложению предшествует такая тяжёлая спайка знаков, как зап-тире, его можно считать новым, самостоятельным:

> Не отделяются запятой вводные слова от союзов, стоящих в начале
>   предложения: *И действительно, он скоро уехал; А между прочим, магазин
>   уже был закрыт; И в самом деле, послышались голоса внизу* (Ч.); *И
>   пожалуй, он правильно поступил.*

**[источник](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=24)**

---

Нацкорпусом ни для чего не пользуюсь: это (для меня) просто указатель частотности употребления того-сего. И - раз цитата - там же мог что угодно изобразить/пропустить корректор.

Для наглядности - пример ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ, кишащий браком:

***[Она умна, мила, наконец хорошо воспитанна.](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86)***

Comment: Почему тогда _и значит_ обособлено, раз это союз?

Comment: Тот же вопрос, но подробней. "Проезжаю родные места, и з. увижу своих племянников" - здесь союз, запятая только перед И. "..Ты не представляешь угрозы, и значит, можешь рассчитывать..." - зачем здесь  вторая запятая? Ошибка?

Comment: "Она умна, мила, наконец хорошо воспитанна."(?!) Стоит добавить, что разбор ошибок можно найти здесь: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/78363861